# Offset Smoker – Kli Rishon or Sheini?

Tags: halacha, cooking-bishul, fire-burning

An offset smoker is a device for smoking food in which the fire is in a compartment (A) which is not completely connected to the cooking area (B), as in the image below:

[image: Original image credit of <https://marksviewfromthebleachers.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/you-dont-need-to-inhale-to-be-a-great-smoker/>]

In theory at least, parts A and B are separate devices and can be separated by a long pipe while reserving the ability to cook. Would this affect the status of the cooking chamber somehow, viz. whether it is a kli rishon?

Comment: "Considering this" Considering what? A device is being heated directly. I don't understand how this could be Kli Sheni. Does it not get hot in there? It's being heated. If I put a pot on a blekh on a fire, that pot is kli sheni???

Comment: @DoubleAA, I've heard that one can theoretically cook an egg in water in a kli sheini on Shabbat (although we don't). In theory at least, parts A and B are separate devices and can be separated by a long pipe while reserving the ability to cook. Would this affect its status somehow, viz. which kli it is?

Comment: The definition of Keli Rishon and Sheni begins only after that they are separated from a heating source

Comment: @kouty, the question is how separate they are from a heating source. FWIW, I would never use a smoker for meat, then milk, (or vice versa) unless I kashered it completely between uses.